# Correct Functions in Excel

Tags: excel, function, syntax

In Microsoft Excel 2010,

If there are two values in two different cells, and there are three conditions for those values as mentioned below:

1. Both are "positive"
2. Both are "negative"
3. One is "positive" and the other is "negative"

If values satisfy 1st condition, result cell should show "ALL POSITIVE" text.
If values satisfy 2nd condition, result cell should show "ALL NEGATIVE" text.
If values satisfy 3rd condition, result cell should show "NEUTRAL" text.

How do I do it in excel? Which functions do I need to use? Can you mention some syntax for above?

Comment: What have you tried? We tend to frown upon people who don't have a go at problems [that are easily solvable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-Excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are in A1 & A2 and that 0 counts as neutral

```
=IF(AND(A1>0,A2>0),"All Positive",IF(AND(A1<0,A2<0),"All Negative","Neutral"))
```

Answer (score 0):

yup, that works. mine is similar =IF(AND(A2<0,B2<0),"Both -ve",IF(AND(A2>=0,B2>=0),"Both +ve","neutral"))